# How to receive a response on a requesting socket without blocking?

Tags: php, zeromq

I've been using a simple request/response (client/server) pattern for a long time and it's been very stable. However, I tried to improve this so that neither the client nor the server could hang if something went wrong with the other.

The original (blocking) pattern is as follows:

**server.php**

```
$zmq = new ZMQContext;
$sock = new ZMQSocket( $zmq, ZMQ::SOCKET_REP );
$sock->bind('tcp://*:5555');
while( true ){
    echo "Server waiting..\n";
    $ping = $sock->recv();
    echo "Acknowledging ",$ping,"..\n";
    $sock->send('Pong');
}
```

**client.php**

```
$zmq = new ZMQContext;
$sock = new ZMQSocket( $zmq, ZMQ::SOCKET_REQ );
$sock->connect('tcp://localhost:5555');

echo "Pinging..\n";
$sock->send('Ping');

echo "Client waiting..\n";
$pong = $sock->recv();
echo $pong," in reply. exiting.\n";
```

This works perfectly well, except if the server dies between receiving the request and sending the response, the client will hang forever.

What I want to do is perform the `$sock->recv` calls without blocking, and allow a timeout if there is no response. I've tried to achieve this though polling. e.g. Replacing the blocking recv call from above with something like this on the client end:

**client.php** (polling)

```
$zmq = new ZMQContext;
$sock = new ZMQSocket( $zmq, ZMQ::SOCKET_REQ );
$sock->connect('tcp://localhost:5555');

echo "Pinging..\n";
$sock->send('Ping');
echo "Client polling..\n";

$poller = new ZMQPoll;
$poller->add( $sock, ZMQ::POLL_IN );
$readable = [];
$writeable = [];
$poller->poll( $readable, $writeable, 1000 );
foreach( $readable as $sock ){
    $pong = $sock->recv();
    echo $pong," in reply. exiting.\n";
    exit(0);
}
echo "No reply after 1s\n";
```

However, I think this approach introduces a risk that the reply received could be intended for another client if two or more clients have sent a request at roughly the same time. I'm **assuming** that the synchronous method guarantees this can't happen, but does the polling method break this?

So, my question in short. **How should a requesting socket receive a reply without blocking, while guaranteeing the message is not intended for another client?**

Comment: Each client connection to the server should be distinct eliminating the chance of the wrong response going to the wrong client.

Comment: I would have thought so, but I'm witnessing a problem where the server replies but the client never gets the message. I can't reproduce it at will, but my best guess was that some other client must be getting the message instead.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *How should a requesting socket receive a reply without blocking, **while guaranteeing** the message is not intended for another client?*

Welcome to the Zen-of-Zero ( incl. Zero-warranty )

Besides the strategies how to circumvent the mutual-deadlock(s) the **`REQ/REP`** dFSA is sure to fall in ( one just does not know how soon it will, but it will ), where I always prefer dual-sided non-blocking `.poll()`-before-`.recv()` loop-scanning, 
**the guaranteed-"*delivery*"-and-"*routing*" is an issue on another level.**

The `REQ/REP` ( documented in ZMTP/RFC(28) ) works, per-se, this way:

> <sub>Each request sent is round-robined among all services, and each reply received is matched with the last issued request.
>
> If no services are available, then any send operation on the socket shall block until at least one service becomes available. The REQ socket shall not discard messages.</sub>

being observed on the `REQ.send()`-side, and

> <sub>Each request received is fair-queued from among all clients, and each reply sent is routed to the client that issued the last request. If the original requester does not exist any more the reply is silently discarded.</sub>

being observed on the `REP.recv()`-side.

The last sentence solved a misappropriated delivery for cases, where `REQ`-side ceased to exist right before `REP.send()` got called.

Messages, on the other hand,
may contain self-validation-of-appropriate delivery ( can validate 'em before a {process|forget}-decision taken ),
may contain a cryptographically guaranteed form of "saving your neck" for cases the payloads get to the wrong hands ( having a Zero-value if not having also the "proper"-Key ) - so may send any-to-all without a Sin of Breaching any content-protection policy ( yet still a rather brutal & resources-wise "expensive" strategy, isn't it? )
all,
indeed all,
depends on your preferences
and levels of robustness acceptable given a level of security-related ( and principally due levels of reasonable ) paranoia was set and mutually accepted as plausible among all domain-problem's relevant participants and risk-owners.

---

### The Best Next Step:

Review all your problem-domain requirements and risks, assess reasonable costs of problem mitigations and decide about a reasonable, yet cost-effective design of custom-specific multi-agent distributed app-level protocol, that will add all requirements that ZeroMQ has knowingly omitted to incorporate into the smart, scalable, almost zero-latency trivial archetypes ( which may not fit as an as-is use-case, as any of your high-level add-on requirements introduce more work to be performed before/during/after a message was due to get delivered )

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. It will take me some time to digest!